# Setting an ItemFileWriteStore for a dojox Datagrid embedded in a Dialog

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have created a dojox.grid.DataGrid embedded in dijit.Dialog programatically. I'm using a dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore for the grid. When I create the ItemFileWriteStore using "url" constructor, it works and the grid gets displayed.

```
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        "url": "data/reportTypes.json"
    }
);
```

However, when I create the ItemFileWriteStore using "data" constructor, nothing is displayed. Grid is absent, without even showing an error.

```
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        //"url": "data/reportTypes.json"
        data: _reportGridData
    }
);
```

Also, in case of "url" constructor (1st scenario), I checked the rowCount attribute after calling `grid.startup()` It was zero. That means rows were not rendered. Whereas in case of "data" constructor (2nd scenario), rowCount is 8, but I **do not see** the grid!
Can a grid not be embedded into a Dialog? What exactly is the problem?
Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem this week and the problem was that when the grid is rendered inside an element where the `displayed` css attribute is `none` the grid will be rendered as wide as it's parent container but only 0 pixels high.

You could try showing the dialog and then programmaticly building the grid inside the open dialog.

Comment: Yeah, calling render() on the grid worked for me! Seems, it has to be called everytime we call setStore() on it.